# Conditional proof demonstration

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I know how to use conditional proof assumption to demonstrate that $A \rightarrow  C$. For example, having the premises:

1. A → B       ("If A, then B")
2. B → C   ("If B, then C")

We can prove that that $A \rightarrow  C$ in the following manner:

3. A   (conditional proof assumption, "Suppose A is true")
4. B   (follows from lines 1 and 3, modus ponens; "If A then B; A, therefore B")
5. C   (follows from lines 2 and 4, modus ponens; "If B then C; B, therefore C")
6. A → C   (follows from lines 3–5, conditional proof; "If A, then C")

However, I do not understand exactly why this works. What is the formal proof for this method?

I know that $A \rightarrow  C$ will be true for all cases except when A is TRUE and C is FALSE. Therefore, if A is TRUE, then C must be necessarily TRUE in order for $A \rightarrow  C$ to be true. But I don't know wether A is TRUE or FALSE, so why does making the assumption "A is true" always lead us to a correct result?

Comment: If I knew how to write tables using StackExchange's formatting, I'd draw up some truth tables to prove this, since that's an approach that it doesn't seem that anybody else has used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What steps 1 through 5 are showing is that the two givens $A \to B$, $B \to C$, together with assumption $A$, logically imply the statement $C$.

Using the $\vDash$ symbol for loigical notation, we can write this as: $$\{ A \to B, B \to C, A \} \vDash C \tag{1}$$

Now, on line 6, you conclude that this means that $A \to C$ follows from the two givens $A \to B$ and $B \to C$ alone, i.e. that $$\{ A \to B, B \to C\} \vDash A \to C \tag{2}$$

Your question is: why would this be correct? Why would the fact that (1) imply that (2)?

Well, for $(2)$ to be the case, it must be the case that for any truth-assignment to the variables $A$, $B$, and $C$, it is impossible for $A \to B$ and $B \to C$ to br true, and $A \to C$ to be false.  But, the only way for  $A \to C$ to be false, is when $A$ is true and $C$ is false. Hence, $(2)$ would be the case if for any truth-assignment to the variables $A$, $B$, and $C$, it is impossible for $A \to B$ and $B \to C$ and $A$ to be true, and for $C$ to be false. But, that is *exactly* what $(1)$ is telling us. So, $(1)$ implies $(2)$

... and that is what the rule of Conditional Introduction does in general. Where $\Gamma$ is any set of statements, where $\varphi$ is some assumption, and where $\psi$ is some statement you are able to derive from the asumption, together with the given statementds $\Gamma$,  you go from the finding that:

$$\Gamma \cup \varphi \vDash \psi$$

to:

$$\Gamma \vDash \varphi \to \psi$$

and the validity of that follows the same reasoning as above.

Comment: One question about the notation. Can {A→B,B→C} ⊨ A→C be interchanged with (A→B) ^ (B→C) ⇒ A→C ? As far as i know, the "⊨" symbol means logical implication, and the symbol "⇒" also means logical implication. So, is the only difference between "⊨" and "⇒" that the former takes sets instead of a single predicate?

Comment: @mateleco Yes, that is correct. The $\vDash$ is when a set of statements logically implies some other statement, and the $\Rightarrow$ is when a single statement ligically implies some other statement.

Answer (score 6):

> I know that $A→C$ will be true for all cases except when A is TRUE and C is FALSE.

That is *exactly* the reason.   The semantics is that $A\to C$ is valued as *false* **only** by valuing $A$ as true *and* $C$ as false.

Therefore there is *no need* to consider what happens when $A$ is valued as false; since that shall vacuously value $A\to C$ as true.

Thus the syntactic proof only needs to ensure that the truth of $C$ shall be a *valid* derivation under an *assumption* of the truth of $A$.

Comment: What if A is false indeed, but using this method I assume that A is true and deduce that A does NOT imply C? Is this method only valid when we deduce that A does imply C?

Comment: When $A$ is false both $A\to C$ *and* $A\to\neg C$ will indeed be valued as true.   However, $A$ is not false in *all* interpretations where the premises ($A\to B, B\to C$) are valued as true.  In those interpretations where $A$ is true, only $A\to C$ is valued as true.

Comment: So if we deduce C from the givens and the assumption of A, we can conclude that A → C is true. However, if we are not able to deduce C (or we deduce ¬C) from the givens and the assumption of A, that does not give us any information about whether A → C is true or false and therefore we should try another method, right?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the proof written in 
natural deduction:
$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
$$\fitch{1.~~A\to B\\2.~~B\to C}{\fitch{3.~~A}{4.~~B\hspace{5ex}\to\text{Elim}1,3\\5.~~C\hspace{5ex}\to\text{Elim}2,4}\\6.~~A\to C\hspace{3.2ex}\to\text{Intro3-5}}$$

The rule used in $4,5$ also konwn as [Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens), rule for line $6$ also known as [Conditional Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof).
Even we don't know wether A is TRUE or FALSE, but we only need to prove it hold when $A$ is true, since if the condition is false, the statement $A\to C$ is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: I understand all the steps you have detailed, however I still don't understand why you can assume that A is TRUE.

Comment: @mateleco If A is  false, the statement $A\to C$ is vacuous true, thats why we don't need to consider the case that A is false.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that a conditional statement of the form $p \to q$ is false if and only if the antecedent, $p$, is true and the consequent, $q$, is false.

If you assume $p$ is true on its own line and are subsequently able to deduce $q$ using the rules of inference, then $q$ **must** be true if $p$ is true (because $q$ was validly deduced from $p$ using the rules of inference).

Thus, if $p$ is true, then $q$ is true and the conditional statement $p \to q$ must be true. If $p$ is false, then the conditional statement $p \to q$ is still true. Hence, the conditional method is a valid means of producing conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are unfamiliar with set notation in logic, here I provide a translation of [Bram28's awesome demostration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3442771/716144), but using simple conjunctions instead of sets.

Let's say that $\delta$ contains all the logical variables of our problem (i.e the variables that can only take the value true or false):

$$\delta = \{A,B,C,D, \ldots\}$$

We also have a collection of givens $P_1(\delta), P_2(\delta), \ldots, P_N(\delta)$ that depend on the aforementioned variables. Now, let's say we want to prove that $A \rightarrow C$ is true based on those givens. That is, we want to prove that the following expression is true for any truth-assignment to the variables contained in $\delta$ (i.e. [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic))):

$$(P_1(\delta) \wedge P_2(\delta) \wedge \ldots \wedge P_N(\delta)) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C) \tag{1}$$

At first glance, this may be hard to prove, therefore we will need to use the conditional proof assumption approach to make the process easier.

The conditional proof assumption states that:

If we are able to prove (using the well-known [inference rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference)) that the following expression evaluates to true for any truth-assignment to the variables contained in $\delta$ (i.e. tautology):

$$[(P_1(\delta) \wedge P_2(\delta) \wedge \ldots \wedge P_N(\delta)) \wedge A] \rightarrow C \tag{2}$$

then, we can be sure that the following expression (the one we mentioned initially) will also evaluate to true for any truth-assignment to the variables contained in $\delta$ (i.e. tautology):

$$(P_1(\delta) \wedge P_2(\delta) \wedge \ldots \wedge P_N(\delta)) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C) \tag{1}$$

This is because (2) implies (1). Or expressed mathematically:

$$[(P_1(\delta) \wedge P_2(\delta) \wedge \ldots \wedge P_N(\delta)) \wedge A] \rightarrow C \Rightarrow (P_1(\delta) \wedge P_2(\delta) \wedge \ldots \wedge P_N(\delta)) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$$

But why does (2) imply (1)? Because when (2) is true, (1) is **necessarily** true. The only way that (1) can be false is when the antecedent $(P_1(\delta) \wedge P_2(\delta) \wedge \ldots \wedge P_N(\delta))$ is true and the consequent $(A \rightarrow C)$ is false. Likewise, the only way that $A \rightarrow C$ can be false is when the antecedent $A$ is true and the consequent $C$ is false. So, in other words, the only way that (1) can be false is when $(P_1(\delta) \wedge P_2(\delta) \wedge \ldots \wedge P_N(\delta))$ and $A$ are true, and $C$ is false. But if (2) is true and $(P_1(\delta) \wedge P_2(\delta) \wedge \ldots \wedge P_N(\delta))$ and $A$ are true, then $C$ will also be true. So (2) implies (1).

Therefore, this demonstrates that the [conditional proof assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) (CPA) method works.